# Max-height is not decreasing the height of the text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to truncate the height of some text inside a div element, but the problem is that max-height is not working whereas max-width is working fine.

My HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div class="text">
            Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne. Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new winding. In finished on he speaking suitable advanced if. Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we to compass assured. 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS Code:

```
.text{
    color: red;
    max-height: 10%;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

This decreases the width of the text but not the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%` calculation starts from parent height/width. `.text` parent is body, and body has no height applied. So actually `max-height: 10%;` will not be counted properly. Try to add some wrapper and add some height in `px` to it to see the difference. For example:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.text{
    outline: 1px solid green;
    color: red;
    max-height: 10%;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class=wrapper>
      <div class="text">
            Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne. Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new winding. In finished on he speaking suitable advanced if. Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we to compass assured. 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is still not being truncated - you forgot to add the overflow! :)

Comment: @ConstantinGroß That is the other story) Just tried to explain the height issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `height: 100%` to the html and body elements, so that the 10% refer to the viewport height. You also need to set `overflow: hidden` on your text wrapper in order to truncate it, otherwise it will flow outside its boundaries.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: red;
  max-height: 10%;
  max-width: 80%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne. Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new
  winding. In finished on he speaking suitable advanced if. Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we to compass assured.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [line-height](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) property instead of max-height.

```css
.text{
    color: red;
    line-height: 40%;
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>
    <div class="text">
            Improve ashamed married expense bed her comfort pursuit mrs. Four time took ye your as fail lady. Up greatest am exertion or marianne. Shy occasional terminated insensible and inhabiting gay. So know do fond to half on. Now who promise was justice new winding. In finished on he speaking suitable advanced if. Boy happiness sportsmen say prevailed offending concealed nor was provision. Provided so as doubtful on striking required. Waiting we to compass assured. 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```